# ESP8266 странная перезагрузка

Tags: arduino, esp8266, esp32

уважаемые пользователи stackoverflow. Тема очень странная - использую arduino uno в связке с esp8266, обмениваюсь инфой через serial port (уно использую как хранилище данных (телефонные номера, датчики)) также использую uno как хаб для подключения датчиков через nrf24l01. Переходим к самому вопросу - по переходе по ссылке "/" вызывается функция handleRoot, которая подгружает тело сайта и вставляет на его страницу сенсоры. **Все работает хорошо**, даже если перезагружать страницу/тыкать на кнопку перехода на страницу. До тех пор пока не перейдешь на другую ссылку (допустим /phoneSettings). **Все продолжает работать, но вот когда я возвращаюсь обратно на "/" - это вызывает перезагрузку ESP8266**. Сначала ESP выдавала

> Exception (28): epc1=0x4020f2f5 epc2=0x00000000 epc3=0x00000000 excvaddr=0x00000000 depc=0x00000000

Потом

> SOFT wdt reset

Потом и вовсе перестала что-либо выдавать и просто уходит в ребут.

**Код ESP**

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
 
/* Put your SSID & Password */
const char* ssid = "MyArduino";  // Enter SSID here

 
ESP8266WebServer server(80);
 
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(100);
 
  Serial.println("Connecting to ");

  Serial.println("<div ><div  >Главное меню</div><div  >Настройка телефона</div></div><div ><ol>   </ol>");

  WiFi.softAP(ssid);
 

//  Serial.print("Got IP: ");  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
 
  server.begin();
  Serial.println("HTTP server started");

  server.on("/", handleRoot);
  server.on("/phoneSettings", handlePhone);
  server.on("/deleteMainPhone", deleteMainPhone);
  server.on("/deleteAdditionalPhone", deleteAdditionalPhone);
  server.on("/additionalPhoneNumber", addAdditionalPhone);
  server.on("/mainPhoneNumber", addMainPhone);
  server.on("/deleteSensor", deleteSensor);
//  server.on("/mainPhoneNumber", !!!!);
//  server.on("/additionalPhoneNumber", !!!!!!);
}
void loop() {
  server.handleClient();
}

void handleRoot() {
  String s = MAIN_page;
  String htmlResponse;
  Serial.print("getSensors");
  String cashData;
  long _timeout = millis() + 4000; 
    while(!Serial.available() && millis() < _timeout){yield();}
    if(Serial.available()){
      cashData = Serial.readString();
      while (cashData.length()){
        String sensorId=cashData.substring(cashData.indexOf(" ")+1,cashData.indexOf(" ")+2);
        htmlResponse = htmlResponse + "<tr><td><form id="+sensorId+" action=deleteSensor> <input type=text value="+sensorId+" name=deleteSensor readonly> </form> </td>";
        cashData.remove(cashData.indexOf(" "),2);
        String sensorType = checkSensorType(cashData.substring(cashData.indexOf(" ")+1,cashData.indexOf(" ")+2));
        htmlResponse = htmlResponse + "<td>"+ sensorType +"</td><td><div id="+sensorId+" class=button onclick=deleteSensor(this)>Удалить датчик</div></td></tr>";
        cashData.remove(cashData.indexOf(" "),2);
        }
        s.replace("@@Sensors@@", htmlResponse);
        server.send(200, "text/html", s);
//      server.send(200, "text/plain", htmlResponse);
      }else{
        server.send(200, "text/plain", "timeout...");
        }
}

void handlePhone(){
  String s = PHONE_page;
  String data;
  Serial.print("getTelephone");
  long _timeout = millis() + 4000; 
  while(!Serial.available() && millis() < _timeout){yield();} 
   if (Serial.available()){
    data = Serial.readString();
    String additionalPhone = data.substring(data.indexOf(' ')+1,data.length());
    data.remove(data.indexOf(' '));
    String mainPhone = data;
    s.replace("@@P1@@", mainPhone);
    s.replace("@@P2@@", additionalPhone);
    server.send(200, "text/html", s);  
    } else {
      server.send(200, "text/plain", "timeout...");
      }
 
      
//      else {
//        server.send(200, "text/plain", "Oops, an error, please, refresh the page");   
//        }
  }

 void deleteMainPhone(){
  Serial.print("deleteMainPhoneNumber");
  long _timeout = millis() + 4000; 
  while(millis() < _timeout){yield();} 
  handlePhone();
  }

 void deleteAdditionalPhone(){
  Serial.print("deleteAdditionalPhoneNumber");
  long _timeout = millis() + 4000; 
  while(millis() < _timeout){yield();} 
  handlePhone();
  }
 String checkSensorType(String type){
  if(type == "1"){
    return "Дверной звонок";
    }
  if (type == "2"){
    return "Дыма";
    }
  }

void addMainPhone(){
  String Phone = server.arg("mainPhoneNumber"); 
  String dataToSend = "addMainPhoneNumber "+Phone;
  Serial.print(dataToSend);
  long _timeout = millis() + 4000; 
  while(millis() < _timeout){yield();} 
  handlePhone();
  }
  void addAdditionalPhone(){
  String Phone = server.arg("additionalPhoneNumber"); 
  String dataToSend = "addAdditionalPhoneNumber "+Phone;
  Serial.print(dataToSend);
  long _timeout = millis() + 4000; 
  while(millis() < _timeout){yield();} 
  handlePhone();
  }

void deleteSensor(){
  String sensorId = server.arg("deleteSensor");
  String dataToSend = "deleteSensor "+sensorId;
  Serial.print(dataToSend);
  long _timeout = millis() + 4000; 
  while(millis() < _timeout){yield();} 
  handleRoot();
  }
```

**Код Uno**

```
// ЭТО СКЕТЧ ПРИЁМНИКА (БАЗА)!!!
//--------------------- НАСТРОЙКИ ----------------------
#define CH_NUM 0x60   // номер канала, должен совпадать с передатчиком (датчик)

// УРОВЕНЬ МОЩНОСТИ ПЕРЕДАТЧИКА
#define SIG_POWER RF24_PA_MAX

// СКОРОСТЬ ОБМЕНА ДАННЫМИ
// должна быть одинакова на приёмнике и передатчике!
#define SIG_SPEED RF24_1MBPS
//--------------------- НАСТРОЙКИ ----------------------

//--------------------- БИБЛИОТЕКИ ---------------------
#include "nRF24L01.h"            // библиотеки для радио модуля
#include "RF24.h"
RF24 radio(9, 10);              // создать радио модуль на пинах 9 и 10
#include "SoftwareSerial.h"     //библиотека для создания сериал порта на любом пине
SoftwareSerial SIM800(4,5);     //создать сериал порт для прослушки на пинах 2,3
SoftwareSerial WIFI(2,3); //TX желтый RX зеленый
//--------------------- БИБЛИОТЕКИ ---------------------

//--------------------- ПЕРЕМЕННЫЕ ----------------------
byte address[][6] = {"1Node", "2Node", "3Node", "4Node", "5Node", "6Node"};     //возможные номера труб
byte callbackData[3];                                                           // массив принятых данных (id от кого, type тип датчика, data что передал)
byte Data[4];                                                                   //массив отправляемых данных (id кому , type кому , id новый , type новый)
byte pipeNo;                                                                    //Байтовая переменная хранения номера трубы для отправки
struct Sensor {                                                                 //Переменная типа struct для хранения данных о датчике
  byte id;
  byte type;
  byte data;
};
Sensor cashDataToSend;                                                          // кешевая переменная для отправки данных
String _response = "";                                                          // Переменная для хранения ответа модуля sim800L
String data;
String additionalInfo;
String command;
//--------------------- ПЕРЕМЕННЫЕ ----------------------

void setup() {
  WIFI.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);    //открываем порт для связи с ПК
  radioSetup();          //ф-я настройки радио модуля
//  simSetup();            //ф-я настройки модуля sim800L
  WIFI.listen();

//  sendSMS("+79520534351","Hi");

//  writePhoneNumber(1,"+79520534351");

//  for(int i =0; i<50; i++){
////    writeNewSensorSettings(0,1,mySensor);
////    clearSensorById(i);
////    delay(200);
//   Serial.print("Info "); Serial.println(eeprom_read_byte(i));
//   delay(5);
//  }
//
//  deletePhoneNumber(1);
//  delay(100);
//  Serial.println(getPhoneNumber(1));

//    writePhoneNumber(1,"+79520534351");
}


void loop() {
  
 if(radio.available()){
  Serial.println("Что-то пришло ,читаю");
  radio.read(&callbackData, sizeof(callbackData));
 if(callbackData[0]==0 && callbackData[1]!= 0){
    registerNewSensor();
 }else if (callbackData[2]!=0){
  Serial.println("Аларм");
  makeCall("+79520534351");
  }   
}

 if(WIFI.available()){
  Serial.println("Есть инфа с wifi");
  data = WIFI.readString();
  Serial.println(data);
  if(data.substring(data.indexOf(' ')+1)!=""){
    additionalInfo = data.substring(data.indexOf(' ')+1,data.length());
    }
  data.remove(data.indexOf(' '));
  command = data; 
  if(command == "addMainPhoneNumber"){
    Serial.println("Команда на добавление главного номера телефона");
    Serial.println(additionalInfo);
    writePhoneNumber(1,additionalInfo);
    }

  if(command == "addAdditionalPhoneNumber"){
    Serial.println("Команда на добавление дополнительного номера телефона");
    Serial.println(additionalInfo);
    writePhoneNumber(2,additionalInfo);
  }  
    
  if(command == "deleteMainPhoneNumber"){
    Serial.println("Команда на удаление главного номера телефона");
    deletePhoneNumber(1);
    }

  if(command == "deleteAdditionalPhoneNumber"){
    Serial.println("Команда на удаление второго номера телефона");
    deletePhoneNumber(2);
  }
    
  if(command == "getTelephone"){
  String s;
  s= s + getPhoneNumber(1);
  s = s + " ";
  s = s + getPhoneNumber(2);
  WIFI.print(s);
  }

  if(command == "getSensors"){
  WIFI.print(parseSensors());
  }
  
  if(command == "deleteSensor"){
    Serial.println("Команда на удаление сенсора");
    clearSensorById(additionalInfo.toInt());
  }
    
 }


}

void radioSetup() {                        // настройка радио модуля
  radio.begin();                           // активировать модуль
  radio.setAutoAck(1);                     // режим подтверждения приёма, 1 вкл 0 выкл
  radio.setRetries(0, 15);                 // (время между попыткой достучаться, число попыток)
  radio.setPayloadSize(32);                // размер пакета, байт
  radio.openReadingPipe(1, address[0]);    // хотим слушать трубу 0
  radio.openWritingPipe(address[1]);       // хотим писать на трубу по первому адресу
  radio.setChannel(CH_NUM);                // выбираем канал
  radio.setPALevel(SIG_POWER);             // задаем уровень мощности передатчика
  radio.setDataRate(SIG_SPEED);            // задаем скорость обмена
                                           // должна быть одинакова на приёмнике и передатчике!
                                           // при самой низкой скорости имеем самую высокую чувствительность и дальность!! (логично)
  radio.powerUp();                         // начать работу
  radio.startListening();                  // начинаем слушать эфир, мы приёмный модуль
} 

void simSetup(){
  SIM800.begin(9600);                      //Скорость порта для связи Arduino с GSM модемом    
  delay(100);
  sendATCommand("AT", true);               //Настраиваем Sim модуль для общения (скорость)
  sendATCommand("AT+CMGF=1", true);        //Включаем функцию отправки сообщений
  }

void makeCall(String phone)                      //ф-я отправки sms 
{
  SIM800.listen();
  sendATCommand("ATD"+phone+";", false);
  WIFI.listen();
}  

void sendSMS(String phone, String message)                      //ф-я отправки sms 
{
  SIM800.listen();
  sendATCommand("AT+CMGS=\"" + phone + "\"", true);             // Переходим в режим ввода текстового сообщения
  sendATCommand(message + "\r\n" + (String)((char)26), true);   // После текста отправляем перенос строки и Ctrl+Z
  WIFI.listen();
}

void registerNewSensor(){
    Serial.println("Новенький");
    radio.stopListening();
    Serial.println("Перестал читать");
    writeNewSensorSettings(callbackData[1],callbackData[2],cashDataToSend);
    Data[0]= callbackData[0];
    Data[1]= callbackData[1];
    Data[2]= cashDataToSend.id;
    Data[3]= cashDataToSend.type;
    Serial.print("Новый id"); Serial.println(Data[2]);
    Serial.print("Новый type"); Serial.println( Data[3]);
    if (waitRadioResponse()){
          Serial.println("Отправил, удачная регистрация");  
          radio.startListening();
          Serial.println("Начинаю слушать");
      }else{
          clearSensorById(Data[2]);
          Serial.println("Нет ответа, освободил id");  
          radio.startListening();
          Serial.println("Начинаю слушать");
        }
  }

bool waitRadioResponse(){
  bool _resp=false;
  long _timeout = millis() + 2000;                                             // Переменная для отслеживания таймаута (10 секунд)
  while (!_resp &&  millis() < _timeout)  {
    _resp = radio.write(Data, sizeof(Data));
    };                                                                         // Ждем ответа или выжидаем таймаут в 2 секунды
  if (_resp) {                                                     // Если есть, что считывать...
    return true;                                                               // ... считываем и запоминаем
  }
  else {                                                                       // Если пришел таймаут, то...
    return false;                                                              // ... оповещаем об этом и...
  }  
}

bool isItFreeCell(int num) {                    //ф-я проверки клетки eeprom на пустоту
  Serial.print("isItFreeCell() <-"); Serial.println(num) ;
  byte cash = eeprom_read_byte((uint8_t*)num);
  Serial.print("Что находится в ячейке num"); Serial.println(cash) ;
  delay(15);
  Serial.print(cash); Serial.print(" = "); Serial.print(cash); Serial.println(" ?") ;
  if (cash == 255) {
    Serial.println(" Да") ;
    return true;
  }
  else {
    Serial.println(" Нет") ;
    return false;
  }
}

void clearSensorById(int id) {                  //ф-я очистки клеток памяти eeprom от сенсора по его id
  for (int i = 10; i < 1000; i= i + 3) 
  {
    if (eeprom_read_byte((uint8_t*)i) == id) 
    {
      delay(10);
      eeprom_write_byte((byte*)i, 255);
      delay(10);
      eeprom_write_byte((byte*)i + 1, 255);
      delay(10);
      eeprom_write_byte((byte*)i + 2, 255);
      delay(10);
      break;
    }
  }
}

void writeNewSensorSettings(byte type, byte data, Sensor& CallbackData) { //ф-я записи нового датчика в память eeprom (дывается id)
  Sensor mySensor;
  mySensor.type = type;
  mySensor.data = data;
  for (int i = 10; i < 1000; i = i + 3) {
    Serial.print("i= "); Serial.println(i) ;
    if (isItFreeCell(i) == true) {
      delay(500);
      if (i==10){
         mySensor.id=1;
        }else {
         mySensor.id = eeprom_read_byte((uint8_t*)i-3)+1;           //Чтение из eeprom 
          }
      Serial.print("Старый id = "); Serial.println(mySensor.id);
        Serial.print("Новый id = "); Serial.println(eeprom_read_byte((uint8_t*)i-3)) ;
      eeprom_write_block((void*)&mySensor, (int*)i, sizeof(mySensor));
      eeprom_read_block((void*)&CallbackData, (int*)i, sizeof(CallbackData)); 
      break;
    }
  }
}

void readSensorSettingsById(int id,Sensor& callbackData){         //ф-я вывода данных о сенсое по id
    for (int i =10;i<500;i= i+3){
       if (eeprom_read_byte((uint8_t*)i) == id) {
        eeprom_read_block((void*)&callbackData, (int*)i, sizeof(callbackData));
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  
void writePhoneNumber(int phoneType, String Phone){      //ф-я записи номеров телефона long поскольку int(16 бит) -32768 до 32767 и по этим причинам не подходит для номера телефона. phoneType - Главный номер =1, дополнительный номер телефона =2; phomeNumber должен быть вида +79.........
    Phone = Phone.substring(3);
    long phomeNumber = Phone.toInt();
    if(phoneType == 1){
      int n=0;
      for(int i=5;i>0;i--){
      delay(50);
      eeprom_write_byte(n, phomeNumber%100);
      delay(50);
      n++;
      phomeNumber/=100;
    }
      }else{
          int n=0;
          for(int i=5;i>0;i--){
            delay(50);
            eeprom_write_byte(n+5, phomeNumber%100);
            delay(50);
            n++;
            phomeNumber/=100;
            }
        }
  }

void deletePhoneNumber(int phoneType){      //ф-я удаления номеров телефона  phoneType - Главный номер =1, дополнительный номер телефона =2;
  if(phoneType == 1){
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
      delay(10);
      eeprom_write_byte(i, 0);
      delay(10);
      }
    }else {
        for(int i=5;i<10;i++){
          delay(10);
          eeprom_write_byte(i, 0);
          delay(10);
        }
      }
  }

String getPhoneNumber(int phoneType){      //ф-я получения основонго номеров телефона phoneType - Главный номер =1, дополнительный номер телефона =2;
  long readPhoneNumber=0;
  String phoneNumber;
  long mnozhitel=1;
  if(phoneType == 1){
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
      readPhoneNumber = mnozhitel * eeprom_read_byte(i)   + readPhoneNumber ;
      mnozhitel *= 100;
    }
    }else{
          for(int i=5;i<10;i++){
            readPhoneNumber = mnozhitel * eeprom_read_byte(i)   + readPhoneNumber ;
            mnozhitel *= 100;
          }   
      }
          if(readPhoneNumber < 1){
            phoneNumber = "";
            }
          else if(readPhoneNumber < 9999999){
            phoneNumber = "+7900";
            }else if (readPhoneNumber < 99999999){
              phoneNumber = "+790";
              }else{
                phoneNumber = "+79";
                }
          phoneNumber += readPhoneNumber; 
          return phoneNumber;
  }
  

  
String waitResponse() {                                           // Функция ожидания ответа и возврата полученного результата
  String _resp = "";                                              // Переменная для хранения результата
  long _timeout = millis() + 10000;                               // Переменная для отслеживания таймаута (10 секунд)
  while (!SIM800.available() &&  millis() < _timeout)  {};        // Ждем ответа или выжидаем таймаут в 10 секунд
  if (SIM800.available()) {                                       // Если есть, что считывать...
    _resp = SIM800.readString();                                  // ... считываем и запоминаем
  }
  else {                                                          // Если пришел таймаут, то...
    Serial.println("Timeout...");                                 // ... оповещаем об этом и...
  }
  return _resp;                                                   // ... возвращаем результат. Пусто, если проблема
}

String sendATCommand(String cmd, bool waiting) {
  String _resp = "";                            // Переменная для хранения результата
  Serial.println(cmd);                          // Дублируем команду в монитор порта
  SIM800.println(cmd);                          // Отправляем команду модулю
  if (waiting) {                                // Если необходимо дождаться ответа...
    _resp = waitResponse();                     // ... ждем, когда будет передан ответ
    if (_resp.startsWith(cmd)) {  // Убираем из ответа дублирующуюся команду
      _resp = _resp.substring(_resp.indexOf("\r", cmd.length()) + 2);
    }
    Serial.println(_resp);                      // Дублируем ответ в монитор порта
  }
  return _resp;                                 // Возвращаем результат. Пусто, если проблема
}

String parseSensors(){
  Sensor cash;
  int num=0;
  String parsedSensors;
  for (int i =1; i<=100; i++){
    readSensorSettingsById(i,cash);
    if(cash.id != 0){
//      Serial.println(cashString.length());
      parsedSensors = parsedSensors+" "+cash.id+" "+cash.type;
      num +=2;
      cash.id=0;
      cash.type=0;
      }
    }
    return parsedSensors;
  }
```

Comment: Библиотека от Espressif некоторых версий обладает чудесным свойством - течь памятью, особенно при работе в роли TCP сервера. У вас свежий SDK?

Comment: Ядро для esp8266 - версии 2.5. Версия самой Arduino ide 1.8.13

Comment: Также , я заметил - не знаю - правильно это или нет , но. Я запускаю проект (подключаю все) - все тихо , но !!! Как только я подключаюсь к esp по wifi , она инициализирует get запрос на url "/", хотя браузер я ещё не открывал и соответственно на "/" не переходил .

Comment: Также заметил странную работу serial порта после "перезагрузки". А именно - вместо команд типо getTelephone или getSensors он начинает писать что-то вроде getT или после getSensors дописывать пробел или переход на новую строку

Comment: Я бы начал с исключения очевидных проблем с железом вроде питания. Если там все впорядке - смотреть код, менять версии SDK. Мои проекты работают на nonos-sdk 2.2.1 (legacy)

Comment: Спасибо, но дело было не совсем в этом

Comment: Так и в чем оно было?

Comment: Добавил ответ в закрепе

Answer (score 0):

Ребят, поскольку с ESP8266 нельзя вывести отладочную информацию, проверяйте - что вы отправляете ей на парсинг страницы/чего-то еще. Зачастую все проблемы - в данных. Не знаю по какой причине, но структура, которую я создавал для отправки - вместо пустых ячеек типа id type data. заполняла их рандомными значениями типа 1 50 84 и отправляла их на парсинг, но! Как ни странно - на сторону сервера приходило уже не 1 50 84, а 190 23 44, не знаю почему, но суть в том, что все починилось банальным определением структуры сразу после ее создания id=0, type=0, data=0. После этого - данные на сервер приходят корректные и все работает классно. Меня учили в вузе - определяй переменные! **Напиши хоть 0 для приличия, но видимо этот урок я попросту забыл.**

```
String parseSensors() {

  Sensor cash; // <--
 
  cash.id=0; // <--

  int num=0;
  String parsedSensors;
  for (int i =1; i<=100; i++){
    readSensorSettingsById(i,cash);
    if(cash.id != 0){
      parsedSensors = parsedSensors+" "+cash.id+" "+cash.type;
      num +=2;
      cash.id=0;
      cash.type=0;
      }
    }
    return parsedSensors;
  }
```